# Setting up cypress tests in Gitlab CI/CD pipelines

Tags: .net-core, gitlab, cypress

I am attempting to create a gitlab CI/CD pipeline that includes automated Cypress tests on a .NETcore project.  I have a collection of cypress tests that I can successfully run locally.  They are stored in the directory:

```
 <project>/Cypress/integration/
```

My Gitlab CI/CD pipeline is successfully deploying and building the 
code on my testing server (Windows Server 2012).  However, after deployment the cypress folder is not present on my testing server.  However, when I build the project locally there is a cypress folder.  In both my local build and the build defined by the gitlab-ci.yaml, the build command is the same:

```
     dotnet publish -c Release
```

That said, during local builds, the content in my /bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1.publish/cypress does not include my locally created tests- just the examples provided by cypress.  The restoring of the node packages is obviously creating a new cypress install.

How can I get my local cypress tests onto my testing server?  Any why does the build done via Gitlab CI/CD and my local build differ in whether cypress gets installed?

I have tried updating my .csproj file to include the cypress directory in the build like so:

```
  <ItemGroup> 
     <!-- include cypress tests in build for automated testing-->
     <Content Include="cypress\**"> 
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory> 
  </Content> 
</ItemGroup>
```

But this gives me an error:

```
... error NETSDK1022: Duplicate 'Content' items were included...
```

Any suggestions on how to get this working?  Below I am including my gitlab-ci.yaml file:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
build:
 stage: build
 tags: 
    - cris .netcore
 script: 
  - echo "removing old files"
  - 'Remove-Item -path D:\DeployedWebApps\cris-automated-tst\* -recurse'
  - echo "dotnet build started"
  - 'dotnet publish -c Release -o "D:\DeployedWebApps\cris-automated-tst\"'
test:
 stage: test
 tags: 
    - cris .netcore
 script:
   - echo "testing"
   - 'npx cypress run'
deploy:
 stage: deploy
 tags:
    - cris .netcore
 script:
  - echo "deploying"
 when: on_success
 environment:
  name: Development
  url: https://cris-automated-tst.gisdata.mn.gov
 only:
   - dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I solved this on my own. The trick was to publish just the Cypress Integration folder rather than the whole Cypress directory:

```
 <ItemGroup> 
     <!-- include cypress tests in build for automated testing-->
     <Content Include="cypress\integration\**"> 
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory> 
  </Content> 
</ItemGroup>
```